# Connecting to server getting "Could not connect to host" using PHP and SOAP Ligth (PERL)

Tags: php, perl, apache, soap

I am struggling to get some SOAP request working using SOAP Ligth and PHP on the requesting side and PERL on the server I am requesting information from. I have never worked with SOAP before.

When printing the trace, etc., the URL I am trying to connect to looks wired: "http://ï»¿192.168.1.101/otrs/rpc.pl". I guess that could be part of the problem (but what do I know...). Here is the trace:

```
Fault message: Could not connect to host
Fault code: 0
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    ["function"]=>
    string(11) "__doRequest"
    ["class"]=>
    string(10) "SoapClient"
    ["type"]=>
    string(2) "->"
    ["args"]=>
    array(5) {
      [0]=>
      string(645) "
userpasswordTicketObjectTicketCreateNumber
"
      [1]=>
      string(35) "http://ï»¿192.168.1.101/otrs/rpc.pl"
      [2]=>
      string(13) "Core#Dispatch"
      [3]=>
      int(1)
      [4]=>
      int(0)
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  array(6) {
    ["file"]=>
    string(54) "/Library/WebServer/Documents/SMICTestProject/index.php"
    ["line"]=>
    int(37)
    ["function"]=>
    string(10) "__soapCall"
    ["class"]=>
    string(10) "SoapClient"
    ["type"]=>
    string(2) "->"
    ["args"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(8) "Dispatch"
      [1]=>
      array(4) {
        [0]=>
        string(8) "user"
        [1]=>
        string(11) "password"
        [2]=>
        string(12) "TicketObject"
        [3]=>
        string(18) "TicketCreateNumber"
      }
    }
  }
}
Fault trace: // Of some reason this ends up after the actual trace
Fault line: 37
```

Here is the code that generates the exception:

```
    try {
$client = new SoapClient(null, array(

    'location'  => "http://192.168.1.101/otrs/rpc.pl",
    'uri'       => "Core",
    'trace'     => 1,
    'login'     => "user",
    'password'  => "password",
    'style'     => SOAP_RPC,
    'use'       => SOAP_ENCODED
));


$ticketnumber = $client->__soapCall("Dispatch", array("user", "password", "TicketObject", "TicketCreateNumber"));
//Here happens a lot of things, but since this code is never reached I skip including it. 

} catch (SoapFault $fault) {
//trigger_error("SOAP Fault: (faultcode: {$fault->faultcode}, faultstring: {$fault->faultstring})", E_USER_ERROR);
echo "Fault message: ".$fault->getMessage()."\n";
echo "Fault code: ".$fault->getCode()."\n";
echo "Fault trace: ".var_dump($fault->getTrace())."\n";
echo "Fault line: ".$fault->getLine()."\n";
echo "Bad SOAP request\n";
echo "REQUEST:\n".$client->__getLastRequest()."\n";
echo "RESPONSE:\n".$client->__getLastResponse()."\n";
echo "</pre>";
exit;
}
```

What is the problem and what how can I fix it? Should I encode the URL...?

I included just what I thought was necessary, please let me know if I should add something. There is absolutely nothing in any logs I can include here, which I find strange itself.

I'm using OpenSUSE/Apache on the server side and Mac/Apache/PHP on the client side.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What you see when you open `http://ï»¿192.168.1.101/otrs/rpc.pl` in browser? And why this weird character is here?

Comment: When I open it in the browser I get: Firefox cannot find the server xn--192-0gau00a.168.1.101. I have no idea why the link looks like that, I don't do anything to add those strange characters.

Comment: It is the same error (could not connect to host). Try remove this weird character and try again.

Comment: (updated my comment above). When I remove the characters in the browser I still Firefox cannot find the file http://192.168.1.101/otrs/rpc.pl. When having the strange characters it complains that the server is not found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an `UTF-8 BOM` in your URL. Use a hex-editor to get it out (and also save all files *without* BOM)

Comment: This solved the problem. How the heck should one find this kind of problem/solution (I know, Stackoverflow...). I tried to save it as UTF-8 wihtout BOM. It looked better but still there was a '?' left. Tried other encodings as well but with the same result. I am using Netbeans, how can one configure it so it's not throwing in unexpected characters/encodings? Thank you very much!

Comment: Well, it was somewhere in the middle, so probably a copy/paste error (BOM's usually only appear at the _start_ of documents). I don't use Netbeans, but I assume they have configurable ways to do it. I'd try to ask either a Netbeans dedicated forum/list or perhaps superuser.com. Google seems to speak about something like `contrib/hexedit` for Netbeans..

Comment: True, I actually copied this code into Netbeans. I guess that was the reasons why this problem occured. I will be more carefull in the future when I copy/paste code. Thanks again.